# Is it necessary to use "self" property in a web worker?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am new to "Web Workers" API. I was reading [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to learn about it. In [one part](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#performing_computations_in_the_background) of it, we have these codes for a "worker" called "fibonacci.js":

```js
self.onmessage = (e) => {
  const userNum = Number(e.data);
  fibonacci(userNum);
};

function fibonacci(num) {
  let a = 1;
  let b = 0;
  while (num >= 0) {
    [a, b] = [a + b, a];
    num--;
  }

  self.postMessage(b);
}
```

I tested that code with and **without** **"self"** property. Both of them are working fine. I could not understand what is the difference. My question is that is it necessary to use "self" on workers codes? Or it is like the **window** object in normal JavaScript codes (that we could use it like `window.document.getElementById("header");` or don't use it like `document.getElementById("header");`)?

If there is any special difference between using "self" and not using it, please someone give me an example that shows the difference. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See the beginning of this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: @idmean, What is your meaning about that? Do you mean this sentence: ```"Thus, using the window shortcut to get the current global scope (instead of self) within a Worker will return an error."```? But that is not related to my question.